# If I flip a nonbiased coin 13 times what is the probability that I get tails 10 times?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Flipping a coin is an independent event, and has a chance of 50% of either heads or tails. So lets say that I flip a coin 13 times, what is the probability that I get 10 tails *in any order/any number of possible outcomes*, in 13 flips?

Edit: *The probability of at least ten tails*

Comment: How many possible outcomes are there?  How many ways are there to choose the $10$ positions of the tails (or the $3$ positions of the heads) out of the $13$ flips?  What have you tried on this problem?

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: exactly 10 tails or at least 10 tails?

Comment: Fixed again, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Let's first find probability for exactly $10$ tails

Select any $10$ tosses: $\dbinom{13}{10}$

Each of these $10$ tosses must get tail $\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^{10}$

Each of these remaining $3$ tosses must get head $\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^{3}$

So, probability  is

$\dbinom{13}{10}\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^{10}\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^{3}$

Similarly we can find probability for $11, 12, 13$ heads also.

So, required probability is

$$\dbinom{13}{10}\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^{10}\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^{3}+\dbinom{13}{11}\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^{11}\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^{2}+\dbinom{13}{12}\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^{12}\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^{1}+\dbinom{13}{13}\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^{13}\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^{0}\\=\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^{13}\left[\dbinom{13}{10}+\dbinom{13}{11}+\dbinom{13}{12}+\dbinom{13}{13}\right]$$

Answer (score 0):

If you want exact 10 tails then the possibility is:
$$\binom{13}{10}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{10}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{13-10}=\frac{13*12*11}{3*2*1}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{13}$$

where $\binom{13}{10}$ find all possible combination.